# Access denied when calling ExportToStream() from a .rpt file

Tags: iis, crystal-reports

I run my web app in IIS (Windows Server 2012 R2) - which uses XML and an .rpt file to generate a PDF. When trying to use `ExportToStream()` in debug mode, I get this exception:

> Access denied. The file may be in use by another program.

I thought this had something to do with permissions on folders, but I wasn't able to fix it. How can I stop my permissions from being denied?

Answer (score 1):

It should the User you logged in into that computer, then set folder access to full control.

Access denied. The file may be in use by another program.
This Error says the file is already open, Check it in task manager and kill it.

Close all PDF file too..it should be open with same name as you generate a new pdf,It must be unique name.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions were denied because I was using a temporary file, located in C:\TEMP. Adding the group "Everyone" with Full Access solved the problem.